# Android - How to execute one loop, get its completion confirmation and only then execute another loop

Tags: android

I am executing second loop after 9 seconds of first loop is executed. This is tricky part. Is there any way where i can get confirmation of first loop being executed and only then second loop i execute. I don't want timer and delay as it is very risky

First Loop :

```
if (!adminpermissiondenied) {
                if (!pattern && !pinorpassword) {
                /*Set Password*/
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "Setting Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("Admin", "Setting Password");
                    devicePolicyManager.setPasswordQuality(demoDeviceAdmin,DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_UNSPECIFIED);
                    devicePolicyManager.setPasswordMinimumLength(demoDeviceAdmin, 5);
                    boolean result = devicePolicyManager.resetPassword("123456", DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "Password set : " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("Admin", "Password set : " + result);
                    /*Set Password ends*/
                /*Set Password ends*/
                }
                }
```

Second Loop :

```
/*Execute Checker Async Task with a delay of 9 seconds after Password is set*/
                    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("Admin", "Executing Checker Task");
                        //Toast.makeText(context, "Executing Checker Task", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        new checker().execute();
                    }
                    }, 9000);  //After 9 seconds of setting password*/
                    /*Execute Checker Async Task with a delay of 9 seconds after Password is set ends*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an interface callback.

For example create an interface like this:

```
public interface OnTaskCompletedListener{
   void onTaskCompleted();
}
```

Then put your first `while` in a method that accepts a `OnTaskCompletedListener`, and once it finishes, calls `onTaskCompleted()`:

```
private void doFirstTask(OnTaskCompletedListener listener){

   while(someConditionIsTrue){
       // execute
   }

   // if we got this far, it means the while has finished its job, 
   // so we can use the listener to notify for completion.
   listener.onTaskCompleted();
}
```

Now put your second `while` loop in another method that start the first task, and listen for completion.

```
private void doSecondTask(){
    doFirstTask(new OnTaskCompletedListener(){       
        // this code will execute when the first method will complete,
        // so you can start here your second loop
        while(someConditionIsTrue){
           // execute
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

can't you make a boolean variable true when you complete first loop and then check this variable before executing second loop   or 
call the second loop from the place where you come to know that first loop is completed.

Comment: for that 2nd loop should be inside the first loop. I dont think that was intended.